# How to show change content of table using paging

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm

I am using paging with uitableview. I have array of 40 objects. In the numberofrowsinasection method, I am returning 10 rows. Its mean total number of pages is four. Within the pagecontrol method, I am implementing the paging. When I like

```
-(ibaction) pagecontrol:
{
    if (pagecontrol.currentpage == 0)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++  )
        {
            cell.textlabel.text = [objectarray objectatindex:i];
        }
    }

    if (pagecontrol.currentpage == 1)
    {
        for (int i=10; i<19; i++  )
        {
            cell.textlabel.text = [objectarray objectatindex:i];
        }
    }

    if (pagecontrol.currentpage == 2)
    {
        for (int i=20; i<29; i++  )
        {
            cell.textlabel.text = [objectarray objectatindex:i];
        }
    }

    if (pagecontrol.currentpage == 3)
    {
        for (int i=30; i<39; i++  )
        {
            cell.textlabel.text = [objectarray objectatindex:i];
        }
    }
}
```

But I found a strange result in uiableview. Is it correct? Where am I doing the mistake in this pagecontrol method?

Answer (score 0):

Do you always have exactly 40 rows or could there be less?

The code you posted starts with a missing method parameter. There should be either no colon or a parameter after the colon (with a data type).

The code you posted suffers from several problems. The biggest issue is you set the text of the same cell 10 times. You need to set the text of 10 cells, one time each.

Regardless of that, you are going about this all wrong. Replace your posted method with this:

```
-(IBAction)pagecontrol:(UIPageControl *)pageControl {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Then, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you should do the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableView *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    int base = pagecontrol.currentPage * 10;
    int index = base + indexPath.row;
    NSString *text = objectArray[index];

    cell.textLabel.text = text;

    return cell;
}
```

This is in addition to your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods.

That's all you need.

BTW - case matters. Don't type everything in lowercase. Type it in properly with the proper case.

Comment: oh yes its working but when i drag page from mouse i am not able to change page its just change page when i click on dots of pagecontrol how can its be possible for me to drag the screen to change the pageindex

Comment: That's a whole other issue. To do that you need four separate table views inside a scroll view. Setup the scroll view for paging.

Comment: but how to insert tables within scrollview table is already the sub class of scrollview

Answer (score 0):

You are using a constant row in paging to use the section in tableview. It differentiates the rows in the page,
like this:

[image]

Set the number of sections in tableview:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 4;
}

// Set rows in section
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch(section){
       case 0:
       return 10;
       break;
       case 1:
       return 10;
       break;
       .....
       .....
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *FirstLevelCell= @"FirstLevelCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:FirstLevelCell];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:FirstLevelCell] autorelease];
    }

    switch([indexPath section]){
        case 0:
        {
            //Add your code
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {
            //Add your code
        }
        break;
        .........
        .........
        .........
        .........
        .........
    }
}

//Reload table view
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i am not using sections i just wanted to show 40 records in array on 4 pages 10 rows for each page

Comment: change the with for cell to fit 10 row in page,page control not set table